# I want to delete an image on longpress on the image in canvas

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, uwp

I have use the given below code to display the image on canvas and now I want to delete the displayed image on the long press on that image. I try the contextmenu for that but it not works. please anybody tell me how i can do it or properly used contextmenu for it

```
private void Stickers1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    var selecteditem = e.AddedItems[0] as StickersImageListModel; 

    Stickers1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;    

    // taking image from a list StickersImageListModel of images and bind with imageitem varaible    
    Image imageitem = new Image();    
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new System.Uri(selecteditem.Imageurl, UriKind.Absolute));    
    imageitem.Source = image;

    //Add the images on canvas    
    my_canvas.Children.Add(imageitem);    
    imageitem.AllowDrop = true;

    // DRag and drop the images on canvas   
    imageitem.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All;    
    imageitem.ManipulationDelta += Drag_ManipulationDelta;    
    CompositeTransform ct = new CompositeTransform();    
    imageitem.RenderTransform = ct;   

    my_canvas.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;    
}
```

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* is not an error description.

Comment: it works in my application

Comment: there is no error in this code but i want to delete the images on longpress the image

Comment: can I use the holding event for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Holding` event for image. However you have to note that Holding event wont be fired for desktop apps instead you have to use `RightTapped` event.
If you are targetting only to mobile apps you can use Holding event

```
 //  imageitem.RightTapped += Imageitem_RightTapped;
            imageitem.Holding += Imageitem_Holding;
            imageitem.IsRightTapEnabled = true;
            imageitem.IsHoldingEnabled = true;

 private void Imageitem_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mycanvas.Children.Remove(sender as Image);
        }

        private void Imageitem_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mycanvas.Children.Remove(sender as Image);
        }
```